# Only oracle user can run sqlplus

Tags: oracle, rhel6

I have a couple of RHEL 6 boxes with Oracle 12.2 server and 11.2 client.  This is the vendor requirement.

On one server I can run sqlplus as any user, on the other server I can only run sqlplus as the oracle user.  Running as any other user gives:
`ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA`

When I say oracle user, I mean the OS user named oracle.

I've checked the listener.ora and tnsnames.ora (in both client and server ORACLE_HOME structures) and both are identical save the host names.

File/directory permissions (ownership and mode) look fine.

Both tnsping and lsnrctl status look fine.

Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Thanks

-- EDIT --

These environment variables are set and are functionally identical.

`set | awk -F=  '/ORA/ {print $1}'
ORACLE_BASE
ORACLE_HOME
ORACLE_SID
ORACLE_TERM
ORACLE_UNQNAME
ORA_SDTZ`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that `hostname` returns a short name on the working server and an FQDN on the non-working server.

I’ve updated /etc/sysconfig/network to set the hostname short and now things work.

I don't know why this is needed but it fixes the problem and right now that all that matters.

Answer (score 0):

As you read in oracle documentation you need also few more variables set. For the users other than oracle you should set example ORACLE_SID which should point to the SID of your database. Also you can consider to set TNSADMIN to point to the correct TNS file.

Comment: Thanks but these are set.  I've editted the question to reflect this.

Comment: Is it same true about TNSADMIN ?

Comment: TNS_ADMIN is not defined on either server.   All servers have tnsnames.ora, listener.ora and sqlnet.ora in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/